# Room Persistence: Error:Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm converting a project to Kotlin and I'm trying to make my model (which is also my entity) a data class
I intend to use Moshi to convert the JSON responses from the API

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String,
    var overview: String,
    var poster_path: String,
    var backdrop_path: String,
    var release_date: String,
    var vote_average: Double,
    var isFavorite: Int
)
```

I can't build the app cause of the following error

> Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
>   Cannot find setter for field.

The examples I found are not far from [this](https://github.com/KucherenkoIhor/Android-Architecture-Components/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ik/exploringviewmodel/entities/Repo.kt)

Ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: which kotlin version is this? Can you also print the full error message? Room should be able to handle that data class properly since it has only 1 constructor that receives all fields.

Comment: Make sure that the constructor parameter's name and type align with what Room expects. This could also occur with a keyword clash with Java. For instance, the Java keyword `static` is allowed in Kotlin but when it is compiled down, it looks like they replace it with another name causing the Room annotation processor to not be able to make the match with the field.

Comment: Can you post your DAO also?

Comment: You solve this, add blank constructor

Answer (score 61):

It's not a problem in your case, but for others, this error can occur if you have @Ignore params in your primary constructor, i.e. Room expects to have either:

- parameterless constructor or
- constructor with all fields not marked with @Ignore

for example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String,
    @Ignore var overview: String)
```

will not work. This will:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String)
```

Comment: This was my case but it doesn't make sense because the official sample for @Ignore uses it the same way: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Comment: @AspiringDev I agree, sounds more like a Room bug than intentional design.

Comment: So the only option is to not use @Ignore fields?

Comment: @FutureShocked you can use it, but outside of constructor

Comment: @daneejela You can have `@Ignore` fields in your primary constructor as well, you just need _some_ constructor without the field that Room can take advantage of. See my answer for details.

Comment: `@Ignore` in a single constructor [is allowed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70762008) with default value and `@JvmOverloads` annotation

Comment: why `var` instead of `val`?

Comment: @ericn  it depends if you want to to be editable or not..

Answer (score 45):

Had a similar issue before.

First I've updated/added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to gradle.

Next, I've used it instead of `annotationProcessor` in gradle:

`kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha4"`

Tha last thing was to create an immutable data class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id : Int,
    val title: String,
    val overview: String,
    val poster_path: String,
    val backdrop_path: String,
    val release_date: String,
    val vote_average: Double,
    val isFavorite: Int
)
```

UPDATE:

This solution works when you have classes for the model and classes for Database in the same Android Module. If you have model classes in Android Library module and the rest of the code in your main module, Room will NOT recognize them.

Comment: Adding `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to module's `build.gradle` file solved the problem for me, thanks!

Comment: Not working with androidx and using 'apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

Comment: [Kotlin] I faced this issue for select query because i forgot to add return type in DAO

Answer (score 44):

I had the same issue. You can move the @Ignore fields to class body. For example :

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String
){
    //here
    @Ignore var overview: String
 }
```

Comment: For me I have to assign default value for the Ignore property.

Answer (score 29):

you need to specify a secondary constructor like so:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int,
    var title: String,
    var overview: String,
    var poster_path: String,
    var backdrop_path: String,
    var release_date: String,
    var vote_average: Double,
    var isFavorite: Int
) {
    constructor() : this(0, "", "", "", "", "", 0.0, 0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add `constructor() ...`, `@PrimaryKey` and replace `val` with `var`. Instead of `constructor()` you can set default values like `var title: String = ""`.

Answer (score 29):

To expand on the answers provided by @evanchooly and @daneejela, you need a secondary constructor to be able to use `@Ignore` parameters in your primary constructor. This is so Room still has a constructor that it can use when instantiating your object. Per your example, if we ignore one of the fields:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id : Int,
        var title: String,
        var overview: String,
        var poster_path: String,
        var backdrop_path: String,
        @Ignore var release_date: String,
        @Ignore var vote_average: Double,
        @Ignore var isFavorite: Int
) {
    constructor(id: Int, title: String, overview: String, poster_path: String, backdrop_path: String)
        : this(id, title, overview, poster_path, backdrop_path, "", 0.0, 0)
    
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your syntax be `constructor(params) : this(params from primary constructor) { }`

Comment: you can give defaults values on the full constructor, then, define an empty one: `constructor(): this(release_date = "", vote_average = 0.0, isFavorite=0)` will do the job. i.e, an empty consturctor which just set default values for ignored fields.

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int? = 0,
    var title: String? = "",
    var overview: String? = "",
    var poster_path: String? = "",
    var backdrop_path: String? = "",
    var release_date: String? = "",
    var vote_average: Double? = 0.0,
    var isFavorite: Int? = 0
)
```

Answer (score 13):

Kotlin allows long as a parameter name, but this won't work when room generates java code.

Comment: This was my problem.  Changing my longitude var from 'long' to 'lng' fixed the error.

Comment: Same, response from api used long for longitude, and it took hours to solve this.

Answer (score 12):

Today I was having this problem. I used `@Ignore`, that is why I got the error. To solve this I created a secondary constructor. So my code looks something like this:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "profile")
data class Profile(
  @field:SerializedName("id") @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id:Long,
  @field:SerializedName("foo") @ColumnInfo(name = "foo") var foo:String?,
  @field:SerializedName("bar") @Ignore var Bar:String?
){
   constructor(id:Long, foo:String) : this(id, foo, null)
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

For me all I had to do was to add a constructor to the data class with empty params sent to it like so:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "posts")
data class JobPost(
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("companyLogo")
    var companyLogo: String,
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("companyName")
    var companyName: String,
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("isAggregated")
    var isAggregated: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @SerializedName("jobID")
    var jobID: String,
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("jobTitle")
    var jobTitle: String,
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("postedOn")
    var postedOn: String,
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("region")
    var region: String
) {
    constructor() : this("","","","","","","")
}
```

Comment: thanks, this should be the accepted answer. @Leonardo Deleon

sometimes, the issue rises up, because we didn't assign a default value on the properties.

```e.g: var postedOn: String = "" // this should fix the error as well```

Comment: Only answer that worked for me using @Ignore params.

Answer (score 11):

I spent an hour trying to figure this out with no success.  This is what I found.  I forgot to add the return type in one of my Queries

this resulted with the POJO error

```
@Query("SELECT userNote FROM CardObject WHERE identifier = :identifier")
suspend fun getUserNote(identifier: String)
```

No POJO error

```
@Query("SELECT userNote FROM CardObject WHERE identifier = :identifier")
suspend fun getUserNote(identifier: String): String
```

Answer (score 9):

I also had this issue, but i realized the problem was that i added the @Embedded annotation to a property that already had a type converter, so anyone having the same problem should check the property declarations for your model class carefully and make sure the @Embedded annotation is not on a property that has a type converter associated with it.

Comment: How to do it then, if we need embedded filed in list property

Answer (score 5):

I think that a good option for resolve it is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id : Int = 0,
    var title: String = "",
    var overview: String = "",
    var poster_path: String = "",
    var backdrop_path: String = "",
    var release_date: String = "",
    var vote_average: Double = 0.0,
    var isFavorite: Int = 0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I was using 'lat' & 'long' as a variable name in the data(Entity) class for kotlin so renaming to latitude & longitude it worked.

**Not working:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_User")
data class User(@PrimaryKey var userId : Int, @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") 
var firstName: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") var lastName: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "password") var password: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "dob") var dob: Long
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "address") var address: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "lat") var latitude: Double
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "long") var longitude: Double) {

}
```

**Working:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_User")
data class User(@PrimaryKey var userId : Int, @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") 
var firstName: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") var lastName: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "password") var password: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "dob") var dob: Long
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "address") var address: String
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "latitude") var latitude: Double
            , @ColumnInfo(name = "longitude") var longitude: Double) {

}
```

Comment: This is the same case with me, thanks for the answer 

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with an entity (all fields were properly-initialized `var`s like a lot of the answers here are suggesting) that included a list of related, non-primitive items like the OP in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44580702/1145905) had. For example:

```
@Entity(tableName = "fruits")
data class CachedFruitEntity(
        @PrimaryKey var id: Long = 0L,
        @Embedded(prefix = "buyer_") var buyerEntity: CachedBuyerEntity? = null
        @TypeConverters(VendorsConverter::class)
        var vendorEntities: List<CachedVendorEntity?> = listOf()))
```

That is, it has an embedded field, and it took me a while to realize that what I actually needed was a type converter for the vendor entity list instead (the compiler wasn't throwing the usual `Error:(58, 31) error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.` So my solution was very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260739/1145905)

This [google architecture components github thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/43) has more info on this misleading error, but not sure if the issue has been fixed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Like it's said in the Room docs, you are **required to make an empty public constructor**. At the same time, if you want to declare other custom constructors, you must add `@Ignore` annotation.

```
@Entity
public class CartItem {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int product_id;
    public int qty;

    public CartItem() {
    }

    @Ignore
    public CartItem(int product_id, int count) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
        this.qty = count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a bug on the library
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/49

Answer (score 1):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62851733

i found this is @Relation's ***projection*** bug! 
not Kotlin language problem.
based google GithubBrowserSample java also happend error, but different error message.

below is my kotlin code:

```
data class UserWithCommunities(
        @Embedded
        var user: User = User(0, null),

        @Relation(parentColumn = "id",
                entityColumn = "users_id",
                entity = CommunityUsers::class,
                projection = arrayOf("communities_id")) // delete this line.
        var communityIds: List<Int> = emptyList()
)
```

right:

```
data class UserWithCommunities(
        @Embedded
        var user: User = User(0, null),

        @Relation(parentColumn = "id",
                entityColumn = "users_id",
                entity = CommunityUsers::class)
        var communityList: List<CommunityUsers> = emptyList()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same bug, much stranger solution: Do not return cursor using reactivex `Maybe<Cursor>` on your Dao. `Flowable`, `Single`, and `Observable` did not work either.

Simply bite the bullet and make the reactive call outside the Dao request.
Before:

```
@Dao
interface MyDao{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM mydao")
    fun getCursorAll(): Flowable<Cursor>
}
```

After:

```
@Dao
interface MyDao{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM mydao")
    fun getCursorAll(): Cursor
}
```

Meta:

```
Android Studio 3.2
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, built on September 17, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.12.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below annotation to any constructor that causes the errors and add a new blank constructor.

> @Ignore

Answer (score 1):

With 2.1.0-alpha6, it turned out to be an invalid return type in Dao. Fixing the return type as expected fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin plugin doesn't pick up annotationProcessor dependencies, So use the latest version of Kotlin annotation processor - put this line at **top of your module's level** `build.gradle` file

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

like

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'  // add this line

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
      ........
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change the compileSdkVersion accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the reason was because the type of data I was getting by query in dao , was not equal to the type of data I was returning.

The type of id in my database was String and I changed the dao from:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM content_table")
fun getIds(): Flow<List<Int>>
```

To :

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM content_table")
fun getIds(): Flow<List<String>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, I had the same problem.

Replace the `Room` Dependencies with that of the latest one present in [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30092550)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Room Database `Entity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Entity):

> Each entity must either have a no-arg constructor or a constructor
>   whose parameters match fields (based on type and name).

So adding an empty constructor and annotating your parameterized constructor with `@Ignore` will solve your problem. An example:

```
public class POJO {

    long id;

    String firstName;

    @Ignore
    String lastName;

    public POJO() {
    }

    @Ignore
    public POJO(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // getters and setters
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure `room` database `column` name and field name in `constructor` are same

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the @Ignore Tags and 'kotlin-kapt' plugin but still this started to happen after updating to **kotlin** to version **1.5.0**.

I ended up updating my room library from version **2.2.5** to **2.3.0** and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

another problem with

```
@Entity
data class SomeEnity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val filed: SomeClass
)

**inline** class SomeClass
```

consider to remove **inline** class

Answer (score 0):

If u use Java. Then my solution was to only ADD @Nonull in the constructor
constructor(@Nonull String,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question has `kotlin` tag to mention that the OP used Kotlin for programming.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31236807)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this error for the longest time. And so I want to give tips to those who are facing the same problem, it may help you.

1. Add all these dependencies or choose the one you will be using : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle
2. Make sure while creating your Class (in my case `Public Class Message`) it implements `Serializable` ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMptR.png))

3. Avoid naming your `attr` with capital in front, it will be hard for the DAO_impl to detect. If you want to then make sure the getter and setter is also capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using datatype name long as a field name

@Entity(tableName = "MyLocations")
data class MyLocationModel(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int = 0,
var name: String,
val stored: Boolean,
val lat: Double,
val long: Double
)

just changed long to lon worked for me

@Entity(tableName = "MyLocations")
data class MyLocationModel(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id: Int = 0,
var name: String,
val stored: Boolean,
val lat: Double,
val lon: Double
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i remove `@Ignore` from one of my field, then it compiled without error

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String,
    val age: Int // removed @Ignore from this field
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, and in my case it was because I had attempted to use Kotlin's unsigned types like UInt and ULong for the columns in the entity class.

So, lesson learned: Kotlin's entity types are not supported by Room, atleast as of Kotlin 1.9.10 and Room 2.6.1

Answer (score -1):

Don't use to dataclass,use normal class instead. This method will solve problem

Answer (score -1):

In my case I wasn't returning type in one of the Dao query hope it helps others
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

For a variation on FutureShocked answer that implements autoGenerate:

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieKt(
        var title: String,
        var overview: String,
        var poster_path: String,
        var backdrop_path: String,
        @Ignore var release_date: String,
        @Ignore var vote_average: Double,
        @Ignore var isFavorite: Int
) {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id : Int = 0

    constructor(title: String, overview: String, poster_path: String, backdrop_path: String) {
        this(id, title, overview, poster_path, backdrop_path, "", 0.0, 0)
    }
}
```