# Android Parcelable don't support default values App Crash

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I have used autogeneration for `Parcelable` implementation in a Kotlin `data` class. The same class is used as an `Entity` in `Room` so I have default values for every constructor params to provide an empty constructor to `Room`. When I try to pass this item as `Parcelable` the app crashes with `UnsupportedOperationException` and this message

> Parcelables don't support default values

The work around for now I have , I just serialize the object with `Gson` and pass it as `String` but I would like to know if there is proper way to handle default values in Kotlin and `Parcelable`.

Here is the class

```
@Entity
data class ProductData(
    //primary key here
    @ ColumnInfo val alcoholRestriction: Boolean = false,
    @Ignore val averageWeight: Double = 0.0,
    @Ignore val hotFoodRestriction: Boolean = false,
    @Ignore val maxOrderValue: Double = 0.0,
    @Ignore val minOrderValue: Double = 0.0,
    @Ignore val orderIncrement: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo var productId: String = "",
    @Ignore val stdUomCd: String = "",
    @Ignore val uomQty: String = ""
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeByte(if (alcoholRestriction) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeDouble(averageWeight)
        parcel.writeByte(if (hotFoodRestriction) 1 else 0)
        parcel.writeDouble(maxOrderValue)
        parcel.writeDouble(minOrderValue)
        parcel.writeDouble(orderIncrement)
        parcel.writeString(productId)
        parcel.writeString(stdUomCd)
        parcel.writeString(uomQty)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<ProductData> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ProductData {
            return ProductData(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ProductData?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }


}
```

Trying to pass is in a bundle and the crash happens on this line.

```
findNavController().navigate(
            Uri.parse("android-app://androidx.navigation/productDetails/$item"))
```

it is set in the nav graph as custom Parcelable variable

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve], including the actual code and the complete stack trace.

Comment: try moving the default values into your constructor

Answer (score 0):

Move your defaults to the constructor, they are mostly useless anyway. Boolean defaults to false and doubles to zero. Only the strings need something.

Also, why make the strings nullable if you assign a default value anyway.

```
@Entity
data class ProductData(
//primary key here
@ ColumnInfo val alcoholRestriction: Boolean,
@Ignore val averageWeight: Double,
@Ignore val hotFoodRestriction: Boolean,
@Ignore val maxOrderValue: Double,
@Ignore val minOrderValue: Double,
@Ignore val orderIncrement: Double,
@ColumnInfo var productId: String,
@Ignore val stdUomCd: String?,
@Ignore val uomQty: String?
) : Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte() ?: false,
    parcel.readDouble() ?: 0.0,
    parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte() ?: false,
    parcel.readDouble() ?: 0.0,
    parcel.readDouble() ?: 0.0,
    parcel.readDouble() ?: 0.0,
    parcel.readString() ?: "", 
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: ""
)

constructor() : this(
   false, 
   0.0,
   false,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   "",
   "",
   "")

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeByte(if (alcoholRestriction) 1 else 0)
    parcel.writeDouble(averageWeight)
    parcel.writeByte(if (hotFoodRestriction) 1 else 0)
    parcel.writeDouble(maxOrderValue)
    parcel.writeDouble(minOrderValue)
    parcel.writeDouble(orderIncrement)
    parcel.writeString(productId)
    parcel.writeString(stdUomCd)
    parcel.writeString(uomQty)
}
```

Comment: then I will not be able to use this class as an entity in Room, it requires an empty constructor and Boolean will not default to false in the constructor unless you assign the default value to it, Room will complain with the compile error as described here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485631/room-persistence-errorentities-and-pojos-must-have-a-usable-public-constructor

Comment: for the nullable Strings I just added the defaults and didn't refactor yet

Comment: @Rainmaker Just add an empty constructor. I updated the example